# How to join together some strings with conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have the next code:

```
string result = string.Join(",", 
someCondition1 ? str1 : string.Empty,
someCondition2 ? str2 : string.Empty,
someCondition3 ? str3 : string.Empty,
//some other conditions like those
......
);
```

If I have:

```
someCondition1 = true; str1 = "aaa";
someCondition2 = false; str2 = "bbb";
someCondition3 = true; str3 = "ccc";
```

Then result looks like "aaa,,ccc" but I need "aaa, ccc" (there is NO empty string).
Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

How about something like:

```
// Or use a List<string> or whatever...
string[] strings = new string[] { someCondition1 ? str1 : null,
                                  someCondition2 ? str2 : null,
                                  someCondition3 ? str3 : null };

// In .NET 3.5 
string result = string.Join(",", strings.Where(x => x != null));
```

Do you really need to have six separate variables though? If you already had a collection of values and conditions (whether separately or together) it would be more elegant.

Comment: or perhaps just `string.Join(",", strings.Where(condition));`, if condition is the same

Comment: @Vlad: I'm not sure what you mean, but we've got three different variables to start with...

Comment: I mean, the chances are high that instead of the 3 variables there is indeed just one source collection. ("Some other conditions like those" means that the number of strings is potentially greater than 3.) In that case, the OP would need just to filter that collection.

Comment: @Vlad: Indeed - that's pretty much the point of my final statement.

Comment: The LINQ-style answer for .NET 3.5 helped tremendously. I was able to use it to join strings from objects where an attribute of those objects needed to be in an array of valid options: `string.Join(", ", Human.Where(x => someArray.Contains(x.Suffix)).Select(x => x.Name));`

Answer (score 1):

What about just typing some if statements?

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

if(someCondition1)
 result.Append(str1);
if(someCondition2)
 result.Append(str2);
if(someCondition3)
 result.Append(str3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing this a lot, you might want to construct your own class to do this for you in a nice way. I'm not suggesting this is the best way, but it's always fun to make these kinds of things:

```
public static class BooleanJoiner
{
    public static string Join(params Tuple<bool, string>[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int curr = 0;
        foreach (Tuple<bool, string> item in data)
        {
            if (item.Item1)
            {
                if (curr > 0)
                    builder.Append(',');
                builder.Append(item.Item2);
            }
            ++curr;
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }   // eo Join
}
```

Usage:

```
        string result = BooleanJoiner.Join(new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "aaa"),
                                           new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "bbb"),
                                           new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "ccc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use like this also

```
string result = (someCondition1 ? str1 + "," : String.Empty + (someCondition2 ? str2
+ ",": String.Empty) + (someCondition3 ? str3 : String.Empty);
```